# Compatibility with the function (ivy-switch-buffer) of ivy-mode and bm (a bookmark package)

Tags: bookmarks, ivy

The package [ivy-mode](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) has the function `ivy-switch-buffer`, which
use the build in variable `bookmark-alist` to incorporate bookmarks to its options.

I use the package [bm](https://github.com/joodland/bm) to store my bookmarks, which use the file in the varaible `bm-repository-file` to save the bookmarks permanently.
I really like this package because it's simple to configure and use,
but the variable `bookmark-alist` has always nil value and `ivy-switch-buffer`doesn't show my bookmarks.

The code `(bookmark-load bm-repository-file)` load the bookmarks from the field `bm-repository-file` to the variable `bookmark-alist`, but it says that the `bm-repository-file` is not in the "standard form"
(The function `bookmark-load`is in the package bookmark+).

Could `bookmark-alist` be synchronized with `bm-repository-file`? 
or, if they can not be synchronized, is there a function that transform the file `bm-repository-file` into such "standard form"?

Answer (score 2):

[Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) uses the vanilla Emacs standard form of bookmarks. It can also use additional kinds of bookmarks that it defines (or that you define), but they are still based on the same overall bookmark-list structure of vanilla Emacs.

Library `bm.el` does not - its "bookmarks" are overlays, and they are not at all compatible with Bookmark+ bookmarks (including the ordinary bookmarks of vanilla Emacs).

FWIW, Bookmark+ can do everything that `bm.el` does, and more. And it is not difficult to "configure" it to have behavior similar to that of `bm.el`.

In sum:

- If you want to stick with `bm.el` then you cannot use its bookmarks in a bookmarks file expected by Bookmark+ or vanilla Emacs. If `ivy-mode` requires using such  bookmarks then you will need to find a way to make it accept `bm.el` bookmarks instead.
- If you instead want to use Bookmark+ bookmarks then:

  - If `ivy-mode` works with vanilla Emacs bookmarks then it will *likely* work with any bookmarks that Bookmark+ creates and uses.
  - You can configure Bookmark+ to have your bookmarks to behave similarly to `bm.el`.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried that `ivy-mode` accept `bm.el` bookmarks, but I don't know enough elisp. I'm gonna "learn" `bm+`. Thanks again.

Comment: (You probably mean Bookmark+, not "`bm+`". Really, the two are unrelated.)